# Не отображается полоса перемотки в Notification Player

Tags: mobile-development, android-notification, exoplayer

Пишу музыкальный плеер и осталось разобраться совсем малость, это как вывести корректно плеер в уведомление.
Пробовал разные методы, разные комбинации но все тщетно.
Все что я пробовал не смогу написать здесь, но обычно у меня получается что-то вроде этого:
[image: То, что у меня получается выполнить.]

И то что я хотел бы достичь:
[image: Цель(!)]

Описание самой проблемы: Плеер работает, переключает треки, останавливается, а так же воспроизводится по нажатию, но он не отображает длительность трека и перемотку (seekBar).
А так же спустя некоторое время (Всегда по разному), примерно около 5 минут уведомление с плеером исчезает и достать его вновь не получается пока через настройки не закрою приложение. Что могло пойти не так???
Простите за код который режет вам глаза, но он тестовый и делался исключительно для тестов.
Благодарю за понимание.
P.s. Треки берутся прямыми ссылками на файл *.mp3.

Мой тестовый код :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button b1, b2;
private TextView textViewStatePlayer;

private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
private SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;
private String urlAlbumLogo = "";
private Context context;
private PlayerNotificationManager pnm;
private int notificationId = 77432;
private MediaSession mediaSession;

@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
    b1 = this.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = this.findViewById(R.id.b2);
    textViewStatePlayer = this.findViewById(R.id.textViewStatePlayer);

    mediaSession = new MediaSession(context, "TAG_MUZMO");

    exoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .setUseLazyPreparation(false)
            .setSkipSilenceEnabled(true)
            .setDetachSurfaceTimeoutMs(0)
            .build();
    exoPlayer.addMediaItems(getMediaItemsTrack());
    exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    exoPlayer.prepare();


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Play
            pnm = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, notificationId, "ch97")
                    .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.not_id)
                    .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.not_desc)
                    .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(mediaDescriptionAdapter).build();
            pnm.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            pnm.setMediaSessionToken(MediaSessionCompat.Token.fromToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken()));
            pnm.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
            pnm.setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            pnm.setUseNextAction(true);
            pnm.setDefaults(1);
            pnm.setUseChronometer(true);
            textViewStatePlayer.setText("Воспроизводится");
            exoPlayer.play();


        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Pause
            textViewStatePlayer.setText("Пауза");
            exoPlayer.pause();
        }
    });

}


public final PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter mediaDescriptionAdapter = new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CharSequence getCurrentContentTitle(@NonNull Player player) {
        return String.valueOf(player.getMediaMetadata().title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getCurrentContentText(@NonNull Player player) {
        return String.valueOf(player.getMediaMetadata().artist);
    }

    // Загрузка изображения из трека
    private Bitmap bmap;
    public PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callbackBM;

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    class LoadBitMap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... vd) {
            try {
                // Здесь берем ссылку на картинку текущего трека
                bmap = Picasso.get().load(urlAlbumLogo).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
            super.onPostExecute(v);
            if (bmap != null && callbackBM != null) {
                callbackBM.onBitmap(bmap);
            }

        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(@NonNull Player player) {
        // Определяет Действия по нажатию на уведомление
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    777, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        } else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    777, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }

        return pendingIntent;
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
        callbackBM = callback;
        urlAlbumLogo = String.valueOf(player.getMediaMetadata().albumTitle);
        LoadBitMap l = new LoadBitMap();
        l.execute();
        return null;
    }
};



public static ArrayList<MediaItem> getMediaItemsTrack(){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://cs9-17v4.vkuseraudio.net/s/v1/acmp/r737HWHPprZNTdn7RfjQe0BqeV6i1ge0eTF7-8AMgH2cCCeWMclPemZsDq580zBQ2-Hx6Ex9ORhRF0WTGQkUZ7PUDwKsOOF2JHcg_Jx4Zx1GlVMK0P5SKRlQHCzfWugGccKFEErHLXQQiLVfRsE8Vy9-a44UAOQqGqu6uFaBEj9HaStP-Q.mp3?siren=1");
    ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MediaItem.Builder mediaItemBuilder = new MediaItem.Builder();
    MediaMetadata.Builder metadata = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

    metadata.setArtist("Strepsils Scot")
            .setTitle("TITLE_MIDLE")
            .setAlbumTitle("https://excel-home.ru/wp-content/uploads/img/800x0/b460795895283861941d4c40178c95a8.jpg")
            .setMediaType(com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC);
    MediaItem mitm = mediaItemBuilder.setMediaMetadata(metadata.build())
            .setUri(uri).build();
    mediaItemArrayList.add(mitm);
    return mediaItemArrayList;
}
```

}

Comment: Ну я ответа не знаю, но я зашел на документацию класс депрекейтнут советуют использовать ExoPlayer Может поменяли бы там гайды есть вот например https://developer.android.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro#1

Comment: @MadokaMagica Я нашел полезную информацию для себя в вашей ссылке и попробую новую библиотеку указанную в руководстве создания базового плеера. О результатах проделанного я сообщу дополнительно, благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @MadokaMagica Человечище, спасибо Большое, я достиг цели над которой я возился вот уже неделю. 
Не без костылей, но все же статья помогла очень.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы максимально подробно ответить на свой же вопрос.
Ответ:
Удалил все старые реализации ExoPlayer и добавил новые от Media3

```
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-common:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.media3:media3-session:1.2.0"
```

Далее  я Создал класс медиа службы и переопределил onCreate()
и объявил в классе сервиса плеер, контекст, PlayernotificationManager.Builder и т.д.

```
private static ExoPlayer player;
private MediaSession mediaSession;
private PlayerNotificationManager.Builder pnm;
private Context context;
private String urlAlbumLogo;
private PlayerView playerView;


    public class PService extends MediaSessionService {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MediaSession onGetSession(MediaSession.ControllerInfo controllerInfo) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Далее сделал метод создания MediaItem листа внутри сервиса... (Для теста и примера)

```
public static ArrayList<MediaItem> getMediaItemsTrack(){
        Uri[] uris = {
                Uri.parse("");
        };
        ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Uri uri : uris) {

            MediaItem.Builder mediaItemBuilder = new MediaItem.Builder();
            MediaMetadata.Builder metadata = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

            metadata.setArtist("Подзаголовок уведомления")
                    .setTitle("Заголовок уведомления")
                    .setAlbumTitle("URL Картинки на уведомление")
                    .setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC);
            MediaItem mitm = mediaItemBuilder.setMediaMetadata(metadata.build())
                    .setUri(uri).build();
            mediaItemArrayList.add(mitm);
        }
        return mediaItemArrayList;
    }
```

В onCreate() я инициализировал плеер, менеджеры и сессии вот так:

```
context = this;
    startService(new Intent(context, AudioPlayerForegroundService.class));
    Log.i("0x000001", "Запуск фоновой службы плеера");

    // Init
    player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    mediaSession = new MediaSession.Builder(context, player).build();
    playerView = new PlayerView(context);
    player.setMediaItems(getMediaItemsTrack());
    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    player.prepare();
    //Create session
    SessionToken sessionToken =
            new SessionToken(context, new ComponentName(context, AudioPlayerForegroundService.class));
    ListenableFuture<MediaController> controllerFuture =
            new MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync();
    controllerFuture.addListener(() -> {
        // Call controllerFuture.get() to retrieve the MediaController.
        // MediaController implements the Player interface, so it can be
        // attached to the PlayerView UI component.
        try {
            playerView.setPlayer(controllerFuture.get());
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
    // create Notification
    pnm = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, 1997, "1997", mediaDescriptionAdapter);
```

в onGetSession вместо значения null я возвращаю mediaSession сделанную в onCreate()

И финал, в главной активности MainActivity.class Откуда стартует приложение, я запустил службу через намерение.

```
// Start Service
    Intent intentStartFService = new Intent(this, AudioPlayerForegroundService.class);
    startForegroundService(intentStartFService);
```

в onDestroy я удаляю сессию и прочую ненужную фигню.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mediaSession.getPlayer().release();
    mediaSession.release();
    mediaSession = null;

}
```

И чуть не забыл... В манифесте не забудьте указать имя сервиса

```
<service
        android:name=".AudioPlayerForegroundService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:permission="TODO"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Вкратце мой код выглядел таким образом:

```
public class AudioPlayerForegroundService extends MediaSessionService {

    public AudioPlayerForegroundService() {
    }


    public static ExoPlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    private static ExoPlayer player;
    private MediaSession mediaSession;
    private PlayerNotificationManager.Builder pnm;
    private Context context;
    private String urlAlbumLogo;
    private PlayerView playerView;

    @OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class) @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
        startService(new Intent(context, AudioPlayerForegroundService.class));
        Log.i("0x000001", "Запуск фоновой службы плеера");

        // Init
        player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
        mediaSession = new MediaSession.Builder(context, player).build();
        playerView = new PlayerView(context);
        player.setMediaItems(getMediaItemsTrack());
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
        player.prepare();
        //Create session
        SessionToken sessionToken =
                new SessionToken(context, new ComponentName(context, AudioPlayerForegroundService.class));
        ListenableFuture<MediaController> controllerFuture =
                new MediaController.Builder(context, sessionToken).buildAsync();
        controllerFuture.addListener(() -> {
            // Call controllerFuture.get() to retrieve the MediaController.
            // MediaController implements the Player interface, so it can be
            // attached to the PlayerView UI component.
            try {
                playerView.setPlayer(controllerFuture.get());
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
        // create Notification
        pnm = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, 1997, "1997", mediaDescriptionAdapter);


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public MediaSession onGetSession(MediaSession.ControllerInfo controllerInfo) {
        return mediaSession;
    }


    public static ArrayList<MediaItem> getMediaItemsTrack(){
        Uri[] uris = {
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),
                Uri.parse("ТУТ ССЫЛКИ НА ТРЕКИ"),

        };
        ArrayList<MediaItem> mediaItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Uri uri : uris) {

            MediaItem.Builder mediaItemBuilder = new MediaItem.Builder();
            MediaMetadata.Builder metadata = new MediaMetadata.Builder();

            metadata.setArtist("Подзаголовок уведомления")
                    .setTitle("ЗАГОЛОВОК УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ")
                    .setAlbumTitle("https://www.fonstola.ru/images/201312/fonstola.ru_139316.jpg")
                    .setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC);
            MediaItem mitm = mediaItemBuilder.setMediaMetadata(metadata.build())
                    .setUri(uri).build();
            mediaItemArrayList.add(mitm);
        }
        return mediaItemArrayList;
    }
```

На этом всё. Было сложно даже написать это... Рад буду помочь если у кого возникнет похожая ситуация.  Отдельное спасибо @MadocaMagica за предоставленную документацию

Comment: Да не за что может тоже пригодиться вдруг делать буду.